# laravel migration error: Can't create table Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database

My laravel migration is failing because the `Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed`.

I checked the types of the columns and the indexes created several times but I haven't found a resolution yet.

Here's the error message I'm getting:

```
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `command`.`fifteenfive_group_members` (errn  
  o: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `fifteenfive_group_members  
  ` add constraint `fifteenfive_group_members_fifteenfive_group_id_foreign` foreign key (`fifteenfive  
  _group_id`) references `client_department_service` (`fifteenfive_group_id`) on delete cascade on up  
  date cascade)
```

In Connection.php line 501:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `command`.`fifteenfive_group_members` (errn
o: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Here are the two migrations involved:

1. For the parent table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateClientDepartmentServiceTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        if (!Schema::hasTable('client_department_service')) {
            Schema::create('client_department_service', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->unsignedInteger('client_id');
                $table->unsignedInteger('department_id')->nullable();
                $table->unsignedInteger('service_id')->nullable();
                $table->unsignedBigInteger('fifteenfive_group_id');
                $table->timestamps();

                $table->foreign('department_id',
                    'client_department_service_ibfk_1')->references('id')->on('departments');
                $table->foreign('client_id', 'client_department_service_ibfk_2')->references('id')->on('clients');
                $table->foreign('service_id', 'client_department_service_ibfk_3')->references('id')->on('service_type');
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('client_department_service');
    }
}
```

2. For the foreign key containing table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateFifteenfiveGroupMembersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        if (!Schema::hasTable('fifteenfive_group_members')) {
            Schema::create('fifteenfive_group_members', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->unsignedBigInteger('fifteenfive_group_id');
                $table->unsignedInteger('fifteenfive_group_member_id');
                $table->timestamps();

                $table->foreign(
                    'fifteenfive_group_id')
                    ->references('fifteenfive_group_id')
                    ->on('client_department_service')
                    ->onDelete('cascade')
                    ->onUpdate('cascade');

                $table->foreign(
                    'fifteenfive_group_member_id',
                    'FK_fifteenfive_group_members_fifteenfive_group_member_id'
                )
                    ->references('15five_id')
                    ->on('users')
                    ->onDelete('cascade')
                    ->onUpdate('cascade');
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('fifteenfive_group_members');
    }
}
```

Also here are screenshots of the tables:

1. Parent table

[image: parent table]

2. Foreign key containing table

[image: Foreign key containing table]

Comment: The columns need to match exactly, so unsigned integer must match unsigned integer, and unsigned bigInteger needs to match unsigned bigInteger

Comment: @aynber in the images above they do match following the migration run. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Is there more to the error message?

Comment: @aynber I just edited the question at the top to include the error message, hope that helps!

Comment: Hmm, I'm at a loss. The columns are the same, and I would expect the collations to be the same if they were both created with Laravel.

Comment: yeah this is a weird one, i'm not sure what's going on here

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the column `fifteenfive_group_id` on the parent table `client_department_service` had to be unique due to the restrictions of foreign key creation listed below:

A FOREIGN KEY constraint does not have to be linked only to a PRIMARY KEY constraint in another table; it can also be defined to reference the columns of a UNIQUE constraint in another table.